# breaking connection when calling web-service through https

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, ssl, https

I'm trying to call web service (written in java) from .NET client app. I'm calling this web-service in a loop and with every call it is returning packets of data. I monitor traffic with fiddler.

When I use http connection everything works correctly. The problem occurs when I try to connect through https. The first call to web service returns correct data (I have 3 requests in fiddler: making tunnel, asking about certificate, calling web-service method). During the second call (only 1 entry in fiddler: calling web-service method) I recieve only part of response which cannot be interpreted as valid xml (because of missing tags). I also recieve

```
Exception:
An error (Unable to read data from the transport connection: The connection was closed.) occurred while transmitting data over the HTTP channel.
```

I configured http binding, co it couldn't be caused by timeouts:

```
<binding name="bdContractorHttpBinding_SSL" openTimeout="00:05:00" closeTimeout="00:05:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:05:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760" >
   <security mode="Transport">
      <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"/>
   </security>
</binding>
```

Do you know what may cause such problems?

**EDIT:** This is code that i put into my button_click event:

```
        MyService.RequestHeader requestHeader = new MyService.RequestHeader();
        MyService.ResponseHeader responseHeader = null;

        MyService.GetDataRequest request = new MyService.GetDataRequest();
        MyService.GetDataResponset response = null;

        requestHeader.RequestID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        requestHeader.Timestamp = DateTime.Now;
        request.Start = start;
        request.Count = count;
        MyService.ServiceClient service = null;

        using (service = new MyService.ServiceClient("SSL_Endpoint")
        {
            service.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "xxx";
            service.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "xxx";
            service.Open();

            responseHeader = service.GetData(requestHeader, request, out response);

            start += count;


            service.Close();

        }
```

Comment: Did you try to [turn WCF tracing ON](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx) (on the client side only of course) and check the log to see if more information are available ?
Do you create the client proxy programmatically, or reuse it ? by different threads ? Post so code maybe it could be helpful.

Comment: I pasted the code that I'm using. I added reference to web servcie from wsdl to my simple WinForms app. Everything is ok with first click of a button but on the next i recieve posted exeception. Whats interesting i've decresed the amount of recieved data (count variable) in one package and it causes the same error but after a few more web-service calls.